# jQuery Cycle delay issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-cycle

Having trouble with jquery cycle not sure what am i doing wrong.
Without delay it all works fine, but I would love to delay the first image
because the slider starts before the first image or two are loaded
I would love to stop it for few seconds and then start.
ANY IDEAS ?

```
$(document).ready(function() {  $('#slideshow').cycle({ 
      fx: 'fade',
      speed: '1000',
      timeout:'4000',
      delay: '1000'
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you show us a fiddle?

Comment: No need for a delay, just use `$(window).load(function() {$('#slideshow').cycle...`. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready

Comment: this actually worked, but now all of the images are showing up at the beginning of the slideshow, need to fix that, and it's all good :)

Comment: #slideshow img { display: none }
#slideshow img.first { display: block }
it works but only first image shows up. I need the rest of the images to show 10 sec after the page first image shows Any ideas ?

<div id="slideshow">
 <img src="image1.jpg" width="200" height="200" class="first" />
 <img src="image2.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
 <img src="image3.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
</div>

Answer (score 1):

if you wanted a 4 second interval between transitions but you want the first transition to occur 2 seconds after the page loads then you would do this:

```
$('#slideshow').cycle({
fx: 'fade',
speed: '1000', 
 timeout:'4000',
delay: -2000
});
```

The 'delay' option gives you an opportunity to change the transition interval of the very first slide.  When the timeout value of the first slide is calculated, the value of the delay option (default is 0) is added to the timeout value

Hope it helps

Comment: thanks for the answer, this method is working if delay number is negative however when i put positive delay ex( '2000') slideshow loads and stops never passing the first image. not sure why ?

Comment: what I'm actually looking for is 4 second intervals between transitions and first transition to occur 9 seconds after the page loads. I tried adding delay '-9000' it was too fast, then i tried '9000' and everything just stopped  :(

Comment: its all fine now  delay: 5000 instead of delay:'5000'  thanks :)

Comment: you mean -5000? and do not forget to accept answer if you find it usefull